# site menu not working correctly

Tags: html

my problem is that everything on my site works fine, until I visit /behandelingen/manage_your_skin.php

When I visit that page, and then I want to go to my homepage, it displays an error. That is because my site is looking for /behandelingen/index.php while the homepage is in the root folder.
How can I code my menu so that no mattter where it's included, it always goes to the index.php in the root

See http://www.o-vita.nl/ for my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your link to /index.php

The slash will take you too the root

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was not that difficult. It solved the problem ;)

Comment: No problem dont forget to mark the question as solved :) and good luck with the rest off your project